Passing custom path to `setup.py`
I have a Python package whose setup.py has the following content:
from setuptools import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from pathlib import Path

PATH_TO_STUFF_INSTALLATION = Path.home()/'place/with/some/stuff'

extensions = [
    Extension(
        '*', 
        ['mypkg/*.pyx'],
        include_dirs = [str(PATH_TO_STUFF_INSTALLATION/'include')],
        library_dirs = [str(PATH_TO_STUFF_INSTALLATION/'lib')],
        runtime_library_dirs = [str(PATH_TO_STUFF_INSTALLATION/'lib')],
        language = 'c++',
        libraries = ['mypkg'],
    )
]

setup(
    packages = ['mypkg'],
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
)

Though it is working, I would like to remove the hardcoded PATH_TO_STUFF_INSTALLATION = Path.home()/'place/with/some/stuff' and put this as an argument to pip so the installation command would be something like:
pip install /path/to/mypkg --path-to-stuff /home/$USER/place/with/some/stuff

Is this possible? How? I guess it has to do with --config-settings, but to be honest I don't understand how to use that.
